# Why does a String causes a IllegalArgumentException by using a SimpleDateFormat?

Tags: java

Why does this code causes an Illegal Argument Exception?

```
final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
dateFormat.format(new Date() + "23:59") // IllegalArgumentException occurs
```

The time was saved as a string. Is this the wrong way?

Comment: `new Date()` is a Date datatype which is already in `EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z` format

Comment: yes this is wrong way, String should match date pattern

Comment: But how can i solve this problem?

Comment: why is there a final?

Comment: since this date format is necessary and should not be changed

Comment: Do you want to parse a date (String to Date) or do you want to format a date (Date to String)?

Comment: i need this output: 2014-01-08T09:34:00 but only dateFormat.format(new Date()) gives me 2014-01-08T01:00:00 as output

Answer (score 3):

Because you're trying to format a String, instead of trying to format a Date. You're thus using [this method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Format.html#format%28java.lang.Object%29) (`Format.format(Object)` and not [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date%29): `DateFormat.format(Date)`), which throws an IllegalArgument, as documented:

> Throws:
>      IllegalArgumentException - if the Format cannot format the given object

A DateFormat formats Dates to Strings, or parses Strings to Dates. It doesn't format Strings.

Comment: +1 though it might be worth mentioning that the concatenation operator is causing `Date.toString()` to be called.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is wrong.change your code to

```
  SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
  dateFormat.format(new Date()) // Now working
```

Your String should match with your date formate or you have to use date object here.

Comment: i need this output: 2014-01-08T09:34:00 but only dateFormat.format(new Date()) gives me 2014-01-08T01:00:00 as output

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat.format(Date)
SimpleDateFormat.format(Object)
```

There are these two methods there in `SimpleDateFormat`.
With what you do you're calling the 2nd one. And as this 
String you pass in is an invalid date, you get this exception.

I think you think that `new Date()` will give you date without 
the time part in Java. No, it gives you the time part too. So your

`new Date() + "23:59"`

becomes something like

`Wed Jan 08 04:13:58 EST 201423:59`

Therefore the problem you get.

Comment: i need this output: 2014-01-08T09:34:00 but only dateFormat.format(new Date()) gives me 2014-01-08T01:00:00 as output

Comment: @Marwief Hm, this code works fine for me. I get 2014-01-08T04:17:53 if I do this System.out.println(dateFormat.format(new Date())); Maybe your system time is set to 1 AM right now. Try it later, should be OK, I think.